# Does laravel support on HHVM Version 3.15.1 stack

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, hhvm

Does it supports on hhvm 3.15.1 and compiler ID: tags/HHVM-3.15.1-0-g87901df9ba74204dda149af0cfbbb016d85df67e current php version 7.0.99-hhvm

Comment: Worth a read: https://laravel-news.com/future-hhvm-hack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) in the docs, Laravel 5.3 and versions above do not support HHVM anymore. The Laravel versions before 5.3 still have support for HHVM.

So, your best way is trying it with a prior Laravel versions or don't use HHVM at all.

The latter choice is (in my opinion) the better because PHP 7 performs way better than the latest HHVM version, plus you have all the great new feature from Laravel 5.4 and (upcoming) Laravel 5.5

Comment: Plus PHP 7 (and higher) receives updates regularly, while HHVM hasn't been updated for months.

Comment: @Loek that's also true, yes!

Comment: @manniL Exactly! so many incompatibility issue are there, so better is to go with php7.